# Formatting for each line of the file that's being read into the console

Tags: java, printf

I'm trying to show covid data in each line  that will be separated into tabs (like a table) and the numeric values will be divided by the thousands separator.

I'm also trying to use a printf statement so i can specify each line to be formatted in that way but im not sure how to do that.

The result I'm looking for:

```
Global       213,752,662         4,519,052        655,952
```

What I'm getting:

```
Global 213752662 4519052 655952
```

My Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class COVIDdata {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       //printing header//
       System.out.println("Name\t\t\tTotal Cases\tNew Cases\tNew Cases");
       System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t7 Days \t\t24 Hours");
       System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
       //opening the file//
       try {
           File file = new File("C:\\Desktop\\COVID-19GlobalData.txt");
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
           while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
               System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
           }
           while(scan.hasNext()) {
               
               System.out.printf("%,d\n" , int);
           }
           scan.close();
           
       
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Error reading file");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%,d\n" , int);` doesn't compile, so is this the code you're running?

Comment: I just used int as a place holder, i dont know how to implement it properly to change everyline of the file im trying to alter.

Comment: You're doing a couple of things wrong.  1) You're adding a new line charcter after every token.  2) You're not using the \t's in our output to match your headers.

Comment: You have no numbers in your program, so what is that a placeholder for? Also, you seem to want 3 numbers printed, so you would therefore need more than one placeholder...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This loop will exhaust the entire file scanner and print the file as-is with no formatting

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
   System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

You need to parse the lines then include the tabs in your output between several numbers. Something like

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = scan.nextLine();
   String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
   System.out.printf("Global\t%,d\t%,d\n", Long.parseLong(parts[1]), Long.parseLong(parts[2]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i want to apply that rule to a full list of countries instead of all my whole list getting changed into "global"? 

`Global 213,752,662 4,519,052
Global 37,969,371 1,042,666
Global 32,558,530 236,272`

Comment: `parts[0]` will be the first column in your text file and you can print that. Since you didn't show the file, I didn't put that in my answer